# Cómo cambiar el contenido de un UITextView en swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Tengo un problema, quiero cambiar el contenido de un `UITextView` mediante código, por ejemplo si mi `UITextView` tiene como contenido un "Hola" quiero que al presionar un botón el texto cambie a "Hello". El problema es que el botón está en un *segue* Modal y el UITextView está en otro `ViewController`.

Así creo mi *outlet* de mi `UITextView`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textoBucle: UITextView!
```

y así creo el *action* de mi botón

```
@IBAction func cambiarIngles(_sender: Any){
    textoBucle.text = "Hello!"
}
```

Pero al presionar el botón me muestra un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí están las dos pantallas, al presionar el botón que dice "Inglés" el texto de la imagen de la izquierda debería de cambiar el texto del UITextView:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: una pregunta hiciste la referencia de ese outlet a tu textview?, cuando estas en tu view controller `@IBOutlet weak var textoBucle: UITextView!` verifica que al lado izquiero de ese outlet este un circulito relleno?

Comment: @MiguelOsorio si esta bien referenciado, lo hice arrastrando el elemento al codio para poder crear mi outlet

Comment: @MiguelOsorio ya intente con tu solucion de colocar mi Outlet como string pero sigue marcando el mismo error.

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa que error imprime en consola?

Comment: @PabloMarrufo Eso ya lo solucione, solo cree una funcion y una variable estatica, ahora mi erro es el como modificar los label de la tabla que se generan solos con el split view

Comment: Publica el código y te podremos ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que estás declarando la variable `textoBucle` como `weak` cuando debería ser `strong`:

```
@IBOutlet strong var textoBucle: UITextView!
```

Si no hay nadie reteniendo (con una referencia `strong`) el objeto, entonces ARC le va a mandar un `release`.